# How to get the Jgroups Message object content as string

Tags: java, string, message, jgroups

I'm using `jgroups` for cluster node communication. I'm sending messages using channel, but unable to get the received message content. Used `msg.getBuffer()` and `msg.getRawBuffer()` methods, but after converting into string getting **SOH SOH** in the outpout. I just want only the message content not the 'src' or 'dest' hosts. How to get that from Message object?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a string as payload, I suggest either

- Set the contents using `msg.setObject("hello world")` and `msg.getObject()`, which returns the string "hello world"

OR

- Set the contents using `msg.setBuffer("hello world".getBytes())` and `new String(msg.getRawBuffer(), msg.getOffset(), msg.getLength())`.

In the first case, you use a helper method of JGroups to set and retrieve the object, in the latter case you do the (de-)serialization yourself.